# Связь python, json и mssql

Tags: python, json, sql-server, python-2.x, python-2.7

Не получается связать python, json и mssql.

Есть тестовый json. Пытаюсь его загрузить в базу в одну ячейку. После этого обратно выгрузить и работать с ним. Все это нужно, чтобы понять, как работает. Но возникли проблемки.. Загрузить, вроде бы? получается нормально, а вот выгрузить и работать с ним - нет. 
Для загрузки в ячейку базы использую это:

```
parsed_string = json.loads(json_string)
cursor.execute("update Table set Status = ? where Name like ? ",(json.dumps(parsed_string), "Blabla")) 
cnxn.commit()
```

Чтобы выгрузить из ячейчки

```
cursor.execute("""select Status from Table where Name like ?""", "Blabla") 
cursor.fetchall()
```

вот запросы для загрузки и выгрузки...
Как дальше работать с тем, что получилось? 
Вывод питона, после выгрузки из ячейки. Не понимаю, что с форматом не так, т.к. в базе хранится все нормально..

```
"{\"orderID\": 42, \"orderContents\": [{\"productName\": \"keyboard\", \"quantity\": 1, \"productID\": 23}, {\"productName\": \"mouse\", \"quantity\": 1, \"productID\": 13}], \
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загрузка:

```
s = json.dumps(DATA)
cursor.execute("update Table set Status = ? where Name like ? ",(s, "Blabla")) 
cnxn.commit()
```

Выкачка:

```
cursor.execute("""select Status from Table where Name like ?""", "Blabla") 
res = cursor.fetchall()
DATA = json.loads(res[0][X])
```

Comment: вы сделали мой день. и поправили еще и синтаксис мой. Можете объяснить, какие значения и что это получает res[0][X]?

Comment: res это резултат запроса, res[0] это первая линия запроса, res[0][0] это первый столбец для первой линнии результата

Comment: интуитивно понимал это, но теперь все точно ясно! спасибо